# Extracting and generalizing "repeated" methods with similar functionality

Tags: java, design, design-patterns

Let's say we have a class with many methods that do something different but can be grouped together as one "kind of functionality". For example, adding a configuration o setting rules up.

Let's go with the rules example. Say we have a class that models a board game, and we have add different rules so when the game is played the rules are ensured:

```
public class Game {
    private RuleManager ruleManager;
    // etc...

    public Game() {
        ruleManager = new RuleManager(this);
        setupGameRules();
        // etc...
    }

    private setupGameRules() {
        if (players.size() == 1)
            setupSinglePlayerRule();
        else
            setupMultiplePlayerRule();

        setupNumberOfTurnsRule();

        setupScoreRule();
    }

    private void setupSinglePlayerRule() { /*...*/ }
    private void setupMultiplePlayerRule() { /*...*/ }
    private void setupNumberOfTurnsRule() { /*...*/ }
    private void setupScoreRule() { /*...*/ }
}
```

This is just an example I just came up with. The actual model is something different but too hard to explain here. The idea and structure, though, is the same than in the example.

I would like to extract all those `setupXRule()` methods somehow into just unit, in term of design. Reasons:

- Makes code clearer
- The rules of the game are not fixed and "hardcoded" in the game class
- Additional rules can be added. Here's what I meant with generalization. I would want any other programmer using this class to define his or her own rules and setting them on the game.

What would be the best approach?

**Update:** I have been thinking about this design:

```
public abstract class GameRule {
    protected Game game;
    protected RulesManager rulesManager;
    protected Rule[] rules;

    public GameRule(Game g) {
        game = g;
        rulesManager = g.getRulesManager();
    }

    // Sets up the rule
    protected abstract void build();

    // Posts the rule to the game, so when it's played the rule is enforced
    public void post() {
        if (rules == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("The rules have not beein initialized yet.");

        rulesManager.post(rules);
    }
}
```

And then we have different rules:

```
public class SinglePlayerRule extends GameRule {

    public SinglePlayerRule(Game g) {
        super(g);
        build();
    }

    protected void build() {
        // sets up the rule using the rule manager internal operation to handle and manage rules
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice question.  A Factory comes to mind, one which would allow other software developers to register new methods with it, but it's unclear how those methods would interact with your game internals.  Instead of calling separate methods, you could use `setupRule("SinglePlayer");`  Are you sure this isn't a *configuration* problem, though?  Providing a well thought-out configuration would allow others to simply encode their rules in an XML or JSON file.

Comment: No, this is definetly not a configuration problem. About the internals, how about what I included in my update? (check new update)

Comment: Ah, so you would instantiate a RuleManager in the new method?  Then I think it comes down to registering all of the rules in a collection of delegates, and then cycling through the collection and running all of the rules during initialization.

Comment: Yes something like that. So how would I do what you suggested?

Comment: I would start looking at using interfaces if I were you. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/interfaces.html

Comment: I think I'd rather stick with abstract classes, to define default behavior and shared internal variables for all subclasses.

Comment: Hmm, apparently delegates are more difficult in Java than they are in C#.

Comment: Can I just say before you worry about this kind of thing you need to clean up where you're passing in the game just to get the rulesManager and then each rule is pushing itself back in rather than having a third component external to either (like a Builder) handle that.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I am not sure I understand what you meant. But some sort of builder is what I am after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a collection that represents all known setup rules.  An master array or list of interfaces (as @StevieV suggests), for example.

I'd put each setup capability into it's own class so that I could name all the methods simply`setup()`.  Each class would either inherit from a shared base class or implement an interface (or both).  The base class and/or interface would have the `setup()` method.

You can populate the master list statically, manually, so you can control the order, or, put a static method in each class that creates an instance of itself and adds itself to the master list (easier to maintain perhaps, but no guarantee on ordering).

Then you need to use applicable rules for any given situation.  So, I'd turn a situation into a first-class object.

So, the rule interface could include an `boolean isApplicable(Situation situation)` method, which you'd run to compose the applicable set for a given situation.

Each rule would have it's own way to determine if it is applicable, for example, if single player, if multi player, etc..  So the interface would have two methods: `isApplicable(situation)`, and `setup()`.  (Alternately, you could have just `setup(situation)`, which would simply do nothing when not applicable.)

Presumably, `setup()` would do what is necessary, however, you can also build a secondary list for any given situation, if you like.

As @RobertHarey suggests, this can be done using lambda's as well, the master collection would be a list of lambdas or lambda pairs for the two methods.

Comment: Before this answer, I ended up implementing something that resembles this very much, butthe `isApplicable` method, which I don't see necessary. Check out my actual code, does it make sense? Is it like what you're saying? http://pastebin.com/DfCuevd8

Comment: Static classes and methods are death to testability, and if the rules are responsible for adding themselves to the list, this adds an unnecessary dependency to the rules and an extra responsibility.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I am using no static methods or classes. An about the rules adding themselves, are you talking about the `post()` method?

Comment: @dabadaba, I think the comment is directed to (those who read) me for suggesting the possibility of using a one line static function to self-register.  Statics are an appropriate concern: I've railed against them myself.

Comment: I was specifically referring to Erik's answer. But yes, I don't think your rules should take on the responsibility for adding themselves to the list. They have no reason to even know they are part of a list.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship, I take your point, while having to maintain a list of all the rules is a source of maintenance concerns, too.  Maybe one could use reflection to find them (as subclasses of some base class) and register them.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: In places where I've needed to do similar tasks, the configuration step always has to be done somewhere, whether it's in a data file or in a Class that hard-codes each association per need (that sounds terrible, but it's actually really flexible). For example, in an ActionScript project, I would hard-code which Factory to use for each question type into a hash, then just pull that factory out of the hash when asked to make the question. In JavaScript with AngularJS, each factory is registered with questionType+'Factory', and we pull it out of the injector by that convention.